# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'text' was corrupted

Tags: c, visual-studio, runtime-error

I'm doing a small project and I ran into a problem, when I want to correct a text that is a little big but not over the array size, I get this massage.
The problem is that I get it only after I input a large text (again not over the array size) and only if I want to exit the main, it print "Goodbye!" and corrupts the text.
Here is the code, I would love to get some help I'm really stuck

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define YES 1
#define NO 0

void main() {

    char text[601], temp[601];

    printf("*************** Welcome to the text cleaner ***************\n\n\n");

    int stop = NO;
    while (stop == NO) {
        //gets text from user
        printf("Please enter text:\n");
        fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);
        //wanted variables
        int word = 0;
        int car = 0;
        int sen = 0;
        int par = 0;
        //value to check if current char is "
        int paren = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(&text); i++) {
            //checks for more than one space
            if (text[i] == ' ') {
                int x = i + 1;
                if (text[x] == ' ') {
                    while (text[x] == ' ')
                        x++;
                    strcpy_s(&text[i + 1], strlen(&text), &text[x]);
                }
            }

            //deletes spaces and adds space if needed before and after ,/.
            if ((i > 0) && (text[i] == ' ') && (text[i + 1] == '.' || text[i + 1] == ',' || text[i - 1] == '\n' || text[i + 1] == '\n')) {
                strcpy_s(&text[i], strlen(&text), &text[i + 1]);
            }
            if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == ',')
                if (text[i + 1] != ' ' && text[i + 1] != '.') {
                    strcpy_s(&temp, sizeof(temp), text);
                    text[i + 1] = '\0';
                    strncat_s(text, sizeof(text), " ", 1);
                    strncat_s(text, sizeof(text), &temp[i + 1], strlen(&temp[i + 1]));
                }

            //replace .. with . and row down
            if (text[i] == '.')
                if (text[i + 1] == '.') {
                    text[i + 1] = '\n';
                }

            //turns CAPITAL letter to lowercase, unless in ""
            if (paren == 0) {
                if (i > 1) {
                    if (text[i - 2] != '.') {
                        if (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z')
                            text[i] = text[i] + 32;
                    }
                }
            }

            //checks if letter should be CAPITAL, unless in ""
            if (paren == 0) {
                if (i == 0 || (i > 1) && (text[i - 2] == '.' || text[i - 1] == '\n')) {
                    if (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z')
                        text[i] = text[i] - 32;
                }
            }

            //checks if enters to "" or exits
            if (text[i] == '"') {
                if (paren == 0)
                    paren++;
                else
                    paren--;
            }

            // counts all parameters necesary
            if (text[i] == ' ')
                word++;
            if (text[i] == '.')
                sen++;
            if (text[i] == '\n') {
                par++;
                word++;
            }
        }

        //prints corrected text
        car = strlen(text) - (par); //calculates like this to ignor all "\n" in array
        printf("\nText after cleaning:\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n%s", text);
        printf("\ncharacters: %d | words: %d | sentences: %d | paragraphs: %d\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", car, word, sen, par);

        //checks if the user wants to continue or exit
        char answer;
        printf("\n\nIf you want to clean another string press (y): ");

        scanf_s(" %c", &answer, 1);
        if (answer != 'y') {
            stop = YES;
        }
        else {
            (void)getchar();
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    printf("\nGoodbye!");
}
```

Here is an example for a text that creates this problem:

"mechanics is        ,   IN the most general sense , the study of forces and their effect upon matter.          typically , Engineering mechanics is used to analyze and predict the acceleration and deformation (both elastic and plastic) of objects under known forces (also called loads) or stresses . subdisciplines of mechanics include..     statics, the study of non-moving bodies under known loads, how forces affect static bodies..Dynamics the study of how forces affect moving bodies. Dynamics includes kinematics (about movement, velocity, and acceleration) and kinetics.
n"

Comment: Please provide a minimal, *runable* demonstration of the problem. That includes the inputs requires to produce the problem.

Comment: `strlen(&text)` - remove the `&`. Not *the* issue though

Comment: Have you tried fixing [all the warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/rro4GPd6q)?

Comment: `strcpy_s` must **not** be used when the source and destination overlap. Use the `memmove` function instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Doesn't `strlen(&text)` return something completely undefined? It will just try to count non-zero bytes at an arbitrary memory address.

Comment: @PMF `text` is an array, so `&text` happens to have the same value (but not type) as `&text[0]` (or just `text` when decaying into a pointer). So in practice it will work, yet will complain about incompatible pointer types.